# Unexpected KeyError When Merging Two Multi-Index Dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, keyerror

I have two multi-index dataframes that I want to merge on a common column in the second level. Trying to outer merge the two dfs returns an unexpected `KeyError` on the final merge key.

I've tested the merge without the multi-index and it works fine. I've also flipped the order of the merge and it seems to always occur on the `right_on` param. Finally, I've confirmed that I can access the erring key-series outside of the merge just fine..

single index merge works fine:

```
[IN]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['121', '345', '123', '146'],
                    'C': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A2': ['A1', 'A3'],
                    'X': ['B0', 'B3'],
                    'Y': ['121', '345'],
                    'Z': ['D0', 'D1']})

fine_merge = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',left_on='A1', right_on='A2')
print(fine_merge)
```

```
[OUT]:
  A1    B   C   A2    X    Y    Z
0  A1  121  K0   A1   B0  121   D0
1  A1  345  K1   A1   B0  121   D0
2  A2  123  K0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  A3  146  K1   A3   B3  345   D1
```

multi-index key works fine:

```
[IN]:
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('left_header', c) for c in df1.columns])
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('right_header', c) for c in df2.columns])

print(df2['right_header','A2'])
```

```
[OUT]:
0    A1
1    A3
Name: (right_header, A2), dtype: object
```

but multi-index merge returns a `KeyError`

```
[IN]:
error_merge = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', left_on=['left_header','A1'], right_on=('right_header','A2'))
print(error_merge)
```

```
[OUT]:
KeyError: 'A2'
```

I am rather confused by this, especially given that if I reverse the merge or such that `df1` is the right and `right_on==['left_header','A1']` the resulting error is `KeyError: 'A1'`

Thanks for the help in advance.

edit: combine, join, concat all yield the following result:

```
combined
  left_header          right_header                 
       A1    B   C       A2    X      Y    Z
0      A1  121  K0       A1   B0  121.0   D0
1      A1  345  K1       A3   B3  345.0   D1
2      A2  123  K0      NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
3      A3  146  K1      NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solutions:

1. Using `combine.first`

   `df1.combine_first(df2)`
2. Using `Concat`:

   `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`
3. Simple `Join`:

   `df1.join(df2, how='outer')`

Comment: thanks for the response Rahul, but it doesn't seem to actually join on the first index, all three yield the same result:

Comment: can you provide a sample output for the same

Comment: yes, sorry I hit add too quickly, added to the question!

Comment: No problem, edit the question and give a sample expected output!! In comments the df will be destroyed!!

Comment: This is what my answer gives you..now put what you want!! the sample expected output

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... my expected output has A1 matching A2, but by using the combine/concat/join, the two tables are simply put together without keying on A1=A2..

Comment: correct! `fine_merge` but with the headers `left_header` and `right_header`